# Writing multiple log files with Log4Net using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, log4net, microsoft.extensions.logging

I have successfully set up logging in my app using Microsoft.Extensions and Log4Net. But what I cannot do is log different information to different log files. With Log4Net natively, I can simply set up two rollingFileAppenders and call LogManager and pass in the name of the RollingFileAppender to which I wish to log. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions even though of course I'm using Log4Net in both places. As far as I can tell, the logger must be choosing the first instance of the RollingFileAppender and using those settings. Has anyone else resolved this problem?

Comment: Show your log4net configuration

Comment: It would appear that this question has been asked and a solution is available here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674910/log-to-multiple-logfiles-with-microsoft-extensions-logging-abstractions

Comment: I didn't follow that explanation at all; it's three year's old. I posted a request for clarification but hoped there might be a more straight-forward (for me, it might be my failure to understand) example somewhere. There can't be only two people on the planet doing this.